Addressing Performance Dip in Long-Term NetLogo Simulations
I'm using a slurm HPC infrastructure to run NetLogo models on and am experiencing a performance issue that occurs consistently after approximately 4'500'000 ticks.
The model starts to exhibit a noticeable and, as observed, empirically predictable slowdown. I have increased RAM from 30 GB to 60 GB per model and despite efforts to manage NetLogo resources, by clearing the shortest path cache every 100'000 ticks and handling data exports in batches, clearing lists at the same frequency.
Here are my questions:

Has anyone faced similar performance issues in long-term simulations in Netlogo?- If so, how did you address them?
Are there any recommended strategies or adjustments to combat such performance dips in extensive simulations?

Below, you'll find a figure where a black line indicates the minimal progression needed for the models to all complete a scope of simulated evolution within the 5-day time frame quota, allocated by the HPC.
I have ways to bring random (green) to the performance of stationary. However, as you can see, eventually all will be too slow...
P.S.: a level of transparency of the graphed lines is governed by the number of agents traversing the street network in the models (so the more transparent, the less agents, the better the performance - although they all suffer the hit at 4'500'000 ticks )


Q1: Have you tried to solve this problem with Uri Wilensky team at NetLogo implementation home-base? Q2: Did your models co-operate ( communicate ) during the simulated evolutions or do they just passively run an orchestrated ( Behaviorspace driven ) coverage of launch parameter-space? Q3: what HPC infrastructure resources do you use - how many nodes ( for what parts of the NetLogo-based distributed simulation infrastructure ), reserved HPC CPU-cores, RAM, node-local-FS, node-remote-FS, user-code socket-based IPC and why?

Q1: assuming you mean the netlogo-users group @Google groups; no I have not yet.
Q2: No, the models just run independently with varying sets of parameters.
Q3: The streetnetwork has 116 thousand nodes. There are 1 to 10 agents traversing it. I have it handle around 30 thousand calls on the streetnetwork. Each tick is a second, I run one years worth of data. I run it on SURF snellius HPC (google will find it). 1 cpu per simulation run (60-GB avai per CPU). Not familiar with this: node-local-FS, node-remote-FS, user-code socket-based IPC

I read up, I think this is current situation:
First I kept data inside the RAM of the netlogo model. Later I saved it in the tmpdir and cleared the cache in Netlogo. This made little difference (the model is generating relatively little data, only around 4 MB after 30 million ticks I suspect). The RAM is needed to suit the NW extension remembering the shortest paths (which I also clear on intervals). After completion I send the files to my personal directory. However, the models dont interact with each other (so no IPC) and not with already produced data. So these should not be of influence

Ad-A1: No, not an uncoordinated body of volunteer programmers, I meant prof. Uri Wilensky, the principal architect & designer of NetLogo, who best knows SWOT-s hidden inside java-based engine, as he headed several major re-factoring of the core engine. Ad-A2: unless you happen to get some java-engine performance tricks from NW, the essence of Divide-&-Conquer ParameterSPACE-covering enables you to just "wait" a bit longer ( 31M5 ticks are not far from current quota limit ), best adapting scheduling tasks without Behaviospace, hard-coded / batch-parametrised on launch (contact HPC HelpDesk)

To me it looks like something in your model is changing over time to slow it down--there are more turtles or they are doing more calculations, and the patrol strategy affects it. The fact that the change in execution speed changes consistently with patrol strategy indicates that the cause is a change in what the agents are doing.
You could use the profiler extension to at least see if the amount of time spent in each procedure changes over time, which could give clues to what is changing. Have it write out its report and reset itself every 1,000,000 ticks or so and run it with high and low values of patrol strategy. See what changes over time: if the time spent in all procedures increases, then maybe the problem is with NetLogo; but I think you'll see that the time spent in 1-2 procedures is increasing because of some change in what the agents do.

Thanks for your reply Steve! And what a concidence, I was just checking trains from Amsterdam to Lodz to see if I could attend your summer course there; I just noticed you posted about it in the user group.
Anyhow, I know for sure the number of agents remains the same. I also know that the 99% of the computations power is concentrated in a function using nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to. I'll follow your suggestion to have profiler report every nth tick! I am fairly sure time-spent will go up drastically after 4'400'000, still very unsure what this would cause though..

strategies are: if not dispatched to call etiher: drive around randomly, remain at location of previous call, or return to a set location for optimal spreading. I am very confused how random could ever over take lazy (waiting at previous) or stationary (optimal distribution) - could not think of anything in the code that could cause such a dynamic. Especially since it happens abruptly at a constant point in ticks...

As always: human error. A node that was unreachable generated a false path which caused all the dispatching to stop and calls to build up, clogging the whole model, leading to these diminishing returns.. End of the day, it was the input data that caused this late onset and consistent performance dip. Thanks for thinking along @Steve Railsback and @user3666197

Feel free to adhere to StackOverflow way to indeed say thank you - by clicking an Up Vote - this is how this community distinguishes good from bad, isn't it?
